# Create a path in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a path in Python without knowing the specify drive. I am trying to create a way for my code on anyone's computer without knowing which root drive they have. I am learning how to try and do this. I am not looking for the answer, I am looking for somewhere I can research to get my answer. Please and Thank you.

Comment: `import os
drives = [ chr(x) + ":" for x in range(65,91) if os.path.exists(chr(x) + ":") ]`

Comment: Did you try [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filesys.html) already?

Comment: By "a path", do you mean a *file* path? If so - a path *to what*? What are the rules that tell you how to make the path? What do you mean by "without knowing the specify drive"? What is "the specify drive", and why would it matter? (Did you know that there are computers that can run Python programs but don't use Windows, and those computers will not use the Windows drive letter system?) What is a "root drive"?

Comment: I can make a file path. I am using panel widget button that grabs a file already. What I am trying to do is basic have a create a path to a directory that will hold another file to help graph.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `pathlib` https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html.

It's been added to the standard library as part of python 3 and will handle file systems across different operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need some sure place to access without knowing root drive in users computer. I will suggest below sample code to access sure location. hence you get sure location on root drive and now it can be used.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['tmp']
'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
```

thanks and regards